# javascript change image when onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a beginner and I am doing a homework and I have a small problem. My task is when onmouseover is on, image1 should be changed to image2. When onmouseout is on, image2 should be changed to image1 
Onmouseover works but onmouseout does not work! 
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DOM_4</title>
</head>
<body>
<img onmouseover = "changePic1()"onmouseout= "changePic2()" id="myImg"           src="bakground.jpg" width="150" height="200">

<script>
function changePic1() {
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "screen.jpg";
   }
  function changePic22(){
   document.getElementByID("myImg").src = "bakground.jpg";
   }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Why my onmouseout does not work? I know there can be better ways to code, but I must use both onmouseover and onmouseout. There should be only HTML and simple javascript codes. (My teacher said so)

Comment: Is `bakground.jpg` spelled correctly?

Comment: @ ᔕᖺᘎᕊ  I know that it is incorrect. But I just had a file with name bakground.jpg.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to check because it's an easy mistake to make :)

Answer (score 2):

Your function name `changePic22()` is incorrect and you have also syntax error `document.getElementByID`

Replace you code to this one

```
function changePic1() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "screen.jpg";
}
function changePic2(){
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "bakground.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks I did not see that I have a incorrect function name ! but that syntax error I cannot find.. Which syntax error did I do?

Comment: Aha I found that!! Thanks!! It works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

JS:

```
function changePic1() {
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "http://res.cloudinary.com/vishakhanehe/image/upload/v1481149848/mickeywaving_ttphnm.gif";
   }
  function changePic22(){
   document.getElementById("myImg").src = "http://res.cloudinary.com/vishakhanehe/image/upload/v1481149848/obama1_c1buc6.jpg";
   }
```

HTML:

```
<img onmouseover = "changePic1()" onmouseout= "changePic22()" id="myImg"           src="" width="150" height="200">
```